White space appears after keyboard dismisses for a few seconds
I'm developing a Flutter app, and I have a page with several input fields. When the keyboard is dismissed, I notice a white space that remains for 2-3 seconds before the UI adjusts. I've tried several methods to fix this issue, but the problem persists.
Here's what I've tried:

resizeToAvoidBottomInset: Setting this property to false reduces the issue, but it causes other layout problems.
Wrapping with SingleChildScrollView and SafeArea: This helps somewhat, but the blank space issue still
occurs when the keyboard is dismissed.
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(): I'm manually closing the keyboard when a button is pressed, but the space still appears briefly after the keyboard hides.

My Widget Code:
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:collection_app/Constants/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:collection_app/Models/arrears_model.dart';
import 'package:collection_app/Providers/loan_provider.dart';
import 'package:collection_app/Utils/custom_dialog.dart';
import 'package:collection_app/Widgets/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:collection_app/Widgets/custom_button_sm.dart';
import 'package:collection_app/Widgets/custom_form_field.dart';
import 'package:collection_app/Widgets/custom_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class CustomerCollectionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  // final Client customer;
  final ArrearsModel arrearsModel;
  const CustomerCollectionPage({super.key, required this.arrearsModel});

  @override
  State<CustomerCollectionPage> createState() => _CustomerCollectionPageState();
}

class _CustomerCollectionPageState extends State<CustomerCollectionPage> {
  //TODO: Save and Print Method should be changed
  Future<void> _addToTemp() async {
    try {
      final provider = Provider.of<LoanProvider>(context, listen: false);

      // Call the provider to save the receipt
      String? errorMsg = await provider.addToTemp(widget.arrearsModel);

      if (errorMsg != null) {
        if (mounted) {
          CustomDialog.toast(context, errorMsg,
              textColor: AppColors.background,
              backgroundColor: AppColors.warningsRed);
        }
      } else {
        if (mounted) {
          CustomDialog.toast(context, "Sucess",
              textColor: AppColors.background,
              backgroundColor: AppColors.successful);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (mounted) {
        CustomDialog.toast(context, e);
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _saveAndprint() async {
    final provider = Provider.of<LoanProvider>(context, listen: false);

    // Call processReceipt and store the result
    String? result =
        await provider.processReceipt(widget.arrearsModel.agreementNo);

    if (result != null) {
      // Check if the result contains "Error"
      if (!result.contains("Error")) {
        // If no error, show success toast
        if (mounted) {
          CustomDialog.toast(context, result,
              textColor: AppColors.background,
              backgroundColor: AppColors.successful);
          // Navigate back only if needed
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      } else {
        // If there was an error, show an error toast
        if (mounted) {
          CustomDialog.toast(context, result,
              textColor: AppColors.background,
              backgroundColor: AppColors.warningsRed);
        }
        // Don't pop the context here
      }
    } else {
      // Handle the case when result is null (if necessary)
      if (mounted) {
        CustomDialog.toast(context, "No Receipt Data Found",
            textColor: AppColors.background,
            backgroundColor: AppColors.warningsRed);
      }
      // Don't pop the context here either
    }
  }

  FocusNode advancePaymentFocusNode = FocusNode();
  FocusNode paidBalanceFocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    advancePaymentFocusNode.dispose();
    paidBalanceFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<LoanProvider>(context, listen: false).fetchArrearsData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final loanProvider = Provider.of<LoanProvider>(context, listen: false);

    double responsiveFontSize(double baseSize) {
      return baseSize * size.width / 375; // 375 is the base width for scaling
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF007BFF),
        title: CustomText(
          text: "CUSTOMER COLLECTIONS",
          fontSize: responsiveFontSize(20),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white, size: size.width * 0.08),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: size.height * 0.45,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFFF0F5F5),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 32.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        _buildInfoRow(
                            "Receipt No:",
                            widget.arrearsModel.agreementNo,
                            responsiveFontSize),
                        const Divider(),
                        _buildInfoRow("Name:", widget.arrearsModel.customerName,
                            responsiveFontSize),
                        const Divider(),
                        _buildInfoRow("NIC:", widget.arrearsModel.nic,
                            responsiveFontSize),
                        const Divider(),
                        _buildInfoRow(
                            "Agreement No:",
                            widget.arrearsModel.agreementNo,
                            responsiveFontSize),
                        const Divider(),
                        _buildInfoRow("Amount:", widget.arrearsModel.loanAmount,
                            responsiveFontSize),
                        const Divider(),
                        _buildInfoRow(
                            "Balance:",
                            widget.arrearsModel.totalBalance,
                            responsiveFontSize),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.05),
                CustomFormField(
                  labelText: "Advance Payment",
                  errorMsg: "Please Enter Advance Payment",
                  prefixIcon: Icons.credit_card_rounded,
                  type: TextInputType.number,
                  focusNode: advancePaymentFocusNode,
                  onEditingComplete: () {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(paidBalanceFocusNode);
                  },
                  controller: loanProvider.advancePaymentController,
                ),
                CustomFormField(
                  labelText: "Paid Balance",
                  errorMsg: "Please Enter Paid Balance",
                  prefixIcon: Icons.money_rounded,
                  type: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: loanProvider.paidBalanceController,
                  focusNode: paidBalanceFocusNode,
                  onEditingComplete: () {
                    paidBalanceFocusNode.unfocus();
                  },
                ),
                CustomButton(
                  size: size,
                  buttonName: "Save & Print",
                  colors: const [Color(0xFF007BFF), Color(0xFF007BFF)],
                  iconOnRight: true,
                  icon: Icons.print,
                  ontap: () {
                    _saveAndprint();
                    Logger().i("Save & Print Button Pressed");
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    CustomButtonSm(
                        size: size,
                        buttonName: "Add",
                        icon: Icons.add_box,
                        colors: const [
                          AppColors.successful,
                          AppColors.successful
                        ],
                        ontap: () {
                          _addToTemp();
                        }),
                    
                    CustomButtonSm(
                      size: size,
                      buttonName: "Reset",
                      icon: Icons.restore,
                      colors: const [Color(0xFFFF6B6B), Color(0xFFFF6B6B)],
                      ontap: () {},
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildInfoRow(
    String label, String value, double Function(double) responsiveFontSize) {
  return Row(
    children: [
      CustomText(
        text: label,
        fontSize: responsiveFontSize(16),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: AutoSizeText(
          value,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: responsiveFontSize(16)),
          maxLines: 4,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

Observations:
The keyboard dismisses correctly, but I see the blank space at the bottom for a couple of seconds before the UI resizes.
How can I ensure that my UI resizes immediately when the keyboard disappears without leaving that white space?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I have attached Screenshots Below



Do you experience the same if you run your app in release mode with flutter run --release?

Thanks for your suggestion! I ran the app in release mode using flutter run --release, and I noticed that the issue does not occur in that mode. It seems like the problem might be related to how the debug mode handles the layout or rendering.
I'll keep this in mind while developing and testing. If I encounter any more issues, I'll be sure to reach out. Thanks again!

You are welcome, debug mode (due to hot reload etc.) heavily affects performance and similar issues can be encountered. It is advisable to test every similar issue in profile or release mode.
